# What should be done with conflicts in wit.ai?

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai

I'm begining work with wit.api chatbot and conducting through their quickstart example. It looks very simple and clear. But it only looks. I can not even create second branch with "missingLocation", becouse I get

> "Conflicts with "The weather is {forecast}"

It's conflict between two branches. I have looked documentation and almost everything found in google. But I have found nothing about story conflicts and how treat them. 
I will be very gratefull for any tips or references in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen occasionally - it's annoying but usually fixes itself after saving and refreshing your stories page or clearing out any unused actions. It can take a couple of tries then it will go green and work all of a sudden.

Comment: I also found that conflicts can occur if some actions are unused. The actions are not being removed by default when they are removed from a story.